# Empty Template while drawing graphs using Django-graphos

Tags: python, django, graph

I am new to Django. I want to draw a google graph using django graphos. I have written small code for that and i am getting empty template..any lead would be appritiated..

**view.py**

```
from graphos.renderers import gchart
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from graphos.sources.model import ModelDataSource
from models import MyCityViews

def get_context_data(self):
    queryset = MyCityViews.objects.all()
    data_source = ModelDataSource(queryset,fields=['city', 'views'])
    line_chart = gchart.LineChart(data_source)
    context = {"chart": line_chart}
    return render_to_response('gchart.html', {'chart': line_chart})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class MyCityViews(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True , null = True)
    views = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['city']
        verbose_name = 'city'
        verbose_name_plural = 'city'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city
```

**gchart.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Graphos</title>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback({{line_chart.as_html}});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
{{line_chart.as_html}}
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where i am doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not pass view object to div block thats why i was not getting HTML view.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
{{line_chart.as_html}}
</div>
</body>
```